# Action mapped with mapDispatchToProps does not take parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

**Parent component**

```
const myParentComponent = ({ sourceValue, classes, doStuff }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponent className={classes.iconWithText} value={sourceValue} onDoStuff={doStuff} />
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    ... 
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: () => dispatch(doStuffAction())
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(myParentComponent));
```

uses

**Child component**

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        console.info(this.props.value);

        this.props.onDoStuff(this.props.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SomeIcon className={this.props.className} onClick={this.handleClick} />
        );
    }
}
```

Ultimately, the action being called itself does nothing more than log:

```
export function doStuff(value) {
    console.info('At doStuff action', value);
    return { type: DO_STUFF, value };
}
```

Technically, everything seems to work, there's no errors. But, that last console.info in the action logs value as `undefined`. I'm pretty sure it's because I map the onClick action like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: () => dispatch(doStuffAction())
    };
}
```

If I provide a paramater like so:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: () => dispatch(doStuffAction('123456'))
    };
}
```

Then the doStuff action logs that 123456 value.

It does seem that the sourceValue being passed to `onDoStuff` from the main component does not have any effect.

> What do I need to do to make sure the original sourceValue is passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is accept a param in the arrow function and pass it on to the action like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: (value) => dispatch(doStuffAction(value))
    };
}
```

In case you have to pass multiple params, you can write it like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: (value, key) => dispatch(doStuffAction(value, key))
    };
}
```

If you have multiple parameters that varies upon usage, say from one component you want to pass value to `doStuffAction` and in some component you want to pass `value` and `key` then its preferred to make the value as an object like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doStuff: (obj) => dispatch(doStuffAction(obj))
    };
}
```

and action:

```
export function doStuff({value, key}) {
    console.info('At doStuff action', value, key);
    return { type: DO_STUFF, value };
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was closer to a solution than I thought ... I just didn't think of trying that. I figured that since I'm basically passing a function reference, it would automatically take the param as I pass it, guess not ...

Comment: glad to have helped